# Human mesh with complex hair particles posing

Tags: animation, rigging, particles, cloth-simulation, hair

I have a human mesh with lots of hair particles that I would like to pose and use the posing animation to set a cloth simulation so the clothing sits realistically1 in the pose position.
When I pose with all the hair connected Blender slows a lot and the clothing animation is kind of out of the question. So I disconnected all the hair particles to do the pose, than the clothing, than the animation (cloth simulation included). But when I reconnect the hair they obviously go haywire because all coordinates changed.(ctr A all transforms didn't help) Any ideas, solutions, better process to obtain the desired result?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the particles hair modifiers after (under) the armature modifier in the modifiers stack?

Comment: Yes, the order is 1. Autorigpro created rig 2. Collision modifier(for the cloth) 3 to 12 particle systems

Comment: Did you try not to disconnect particles, but turn off their visibility (screen icon) only?

Comment: I discovered one of the main problems in the meantime. When using Autorigpro, for some reason I don’t understand, the vertex groups are deleted and replaced with new ones generated by Autorig. I suppose it has to do with the parenting of the bones. So I’ll try to save two instances of the same file. One before rigging and one after; then copy the vertex groups from the unrigged one to the rigged one and see how that goes.

Comment: ok so copying the vertex groups breaks the pose and cancels the rig parenting somehow, so not an option.